# Import Multiple images and export array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, next.js

Sorry if it seems a bit confusing, I'll try to be as simple and put as much demonstration as possible.

**The problem**

I have a file that needs to import a bunch of images (for now 65 images). In order not to be a manual process, even when adding a new image in the folder and already being 'automatically detected' I created a function to import everything. However, I need to 'export' this function into an object like this:

```
const brandsAdds = [
  {
    label: "brand1",
    value: "brand1",
    logo: Object,
  },
  {
    label: "brand2",
    value: "brand2",
    logo: Object,
  },
  ...
];
```

How am I importing all the images:

```
  // Import all images in folder
  function importAll(r) {
    let images = {};
    r.keys().map((item, index) => {
      images[item.replace("./", "").slice(0, -4)] = r(item).default;
    });
    return images;
  }

  // Variable for easy access to data
  const image = importAll(
    require.context("../", false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg|gif)$/)
  );
```

**Demo**

> Automated process:
> https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-sun-n75j5?file=/pages/index.js
>
> Result:
> [Print result: what must be converted and how](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRx9R.png)

> Manual process:
> https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-sun-n75j5?file=/pages/index_manual.js
>
> Result:
> [Print result manual process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3j4Sa.png)

I'm using next.js and this file that will export an array object will be used in another component. The file is currently over 300 lines long as I'm calling it image by image.

Would there be any way to import all the images by adding them to the array with "label:" and "value:" with the filename and "logo:" with the image path (next.js)?

Comment: i couldn't see the console.log from sandbox, could you share your current result ?

Comment: Are all your images of same dimensions?

Comment: Sorry... Codesandbox was having an error in the code so it wasn't displaying console.log. I've already fixed and added the outputs in the message above!
About the dimensions, no... They don't have the same dimensions, they vary in width and height.

Comment: To clarify, are you asking how to convert what you get in `images` to something with the `brandsAdds` format?

Comment: Yes! Convert "images" with format "brandAdds"